# Tag android-studio está a ser bem utilizada?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

Estava aqui a ver uma pergunta sobre Android e deparo-me, como quase sempre, com a tag [<kbd>android-studio</kbd>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) usada indevidamente. Então ando a ver essas perguntas e a remover a tag onde não for necessária.

Estava a pensar como poderíamos resolver este problema que sei que também acontece com outros IDE's.

Comment: Se já não tem na wiki, poderia colocar os casos onde ela deva ser adicionada e uns exmplos de uso

Comment: @rray já fiz isso, vê o que achas.

Comment: Este é um problema generalizado dessas *tags* de IDE. As pessoas acham que programação é algo meio mágico. Elas usam a linguagem de programação como se fossem o Word. Elas não entendem o que estão fazendo. Então elas acham que aquilo é o mais importante do trabalho dela. A única solução que vejo é sempre tirar a *tag* quando o problema não é com o IDE especificamente. Pode ficar falando para a pessoa sobre isto para ver se ela aprende, mas em geral, ela não vai se importar muito, ela só quer ver o código "funcionando". Seria legal ter uma pergunta que possa ser *linkada* para ensinar isso.

Comment: @bigown não entendi a parte de ter uma pergunta para ensinar isso.

Comment: Mostrar que IDE é não linguagem, não é compilador. Aí pode postar sempre que a pessoa *taguear* errado para ver se ela aprende.

Comment: @bigown mas com uma pergunta já existente no site? ou no meta?

Comment: @bigown tipo o meu comentário? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101229/perguntas-e-respostas

Comment: É, só que algo mais completo, aí só *linka* pra lá.

Comment: @bigown se quiseres criar uma resposta aqui depois podemos linkar para essa resposta ;)

Comment: Acho que seria coisa p/ o site principal mesmo.

Comment: @bigown na help do site?

Comment: Não, deve fazer uma pergunta. É assunto de programação, não de funcionamento do site.

Comment: Vide os enganos com C/C++, code blocks, gcc, delphi/pascal :P.

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101691/o-que-%C3%A9-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ide-e-compilador)

Comment: Se alguém tiver alguma ideia do que pode ser melhorado lá para ajudar os novatos, é só falar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primeira coisa a fazer pode ser revisar o artigo da Central de Ajuda [sobre tags](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Onde ele pode melhorar, onde pode ser mais conciso, onde ele pode estar sendo confuso ou desinteressante. Não vejo nada que possa ser feito para melhorar o uso *dessa tag* que não possa ser feito no geral. Ela só é um caso mais suscetível a ser má utilizada.

A ideia do @bigown de ter uma "pergunta modelo" - pelo que entendi - me parece boa. Eu sempre sou da teoria de que as pessoas aprendem muito melhor por observação e bons exemplos do que com alguém dizendo o que tem que fazer, ou que não sabem o que estão fazendo, ou que tem preguiça.

E a vantagem é que qualquer pergunta pode ser uma pergunta modelo, desde que seja uma das centenas de perguntas sobre IDEs que têm as tags certas, ou uma das sobre linguagens de programação (ou plataformas) que *não* tem tags de IDEs. Qualquer pergunta assim pode ser usada como exemplo, então não faltam candidatos.

De maneira paralela a isso, hoje e sempre, a melhor maneira de resolver esses problemas é: resolver você mesmo - como o @JorgeB vem fazendo. Esse é o maior poder que o site dá.
A melhor maneira de convencer alguém a não bagunçar um quarto, é mantê-lo sempre organizado.

Comment: [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101691/o-que-%C3%A9-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ide-e-compilador)